# Folding Set to make a new Set

Tags: f#

Say I have a type `Prop` for propositions:

```
type Prop = 
    | P of string
    | Disjunction of Prop * Prop
    | Conjunction of Prop * Prop 
    | Negation of Prop
```

Where:

```
• A "p" representing the atom P,
• Disjunction(A "P", A "q") representing the proposition P ∨ q. 
• Conjunction(A "P", A "q") representing the proposition P ∧ q. 
• Negation(A "P") representing the proposition ¬P.
```

I'm supposed to use a set-based representation of formulas in disjunctive normal form. Since conjunction is commutative, associative and (a ∧ a) is equivalent to a it is convenient to represent a basic conjunct bc by its set of literals litOf(bc).

bc is defined as: A literal is an atom or the negation of an atom and a basic conjunct is a conjunction of literals

This leads me to the function for `litOf`:

```
let litOf bc = 
    Set.fold (fun acc (Con(x, y)) -> Set.add (x, y) acc) Set.empty bc
```

I'm pretty sure my `litOf` is wrong, and I get an error on the `(Con(x,y))` part saying: "Incomplete pattern m
atches on this expression. For example, the value 'Dis (_, _)' may indicate a cas
e not covered by the pattern(s).", which I also have no clue what actually means in this context.

Any hints to how I can procede?

Comment: Not sure I understand everything here, but fun acc (Con(x, y)) is probably a match expression how I read it, and as such you are missing the rest of the "matching" (from the unions).

It would of course help very much om the code was here in a "running" state: [MCVE] http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: An example of working and tested code for creating DNF in F# can be found [here](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning/prop.fs#L407). This has much more detail than you are asking will take days to understand it all as it also includes parsing and pretty printing. Also you should get the book to really understand it. Thus it is a comment. There is [examples](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/Examples/prop.fsx) for using with a  REPL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your example type `Prop` changed on the way from keyboard to here, and orginally looked like this:

```
type Prop = 
    | P of string
    | Dis of Prop * Prop
    | Con of Prop * Prop 
    | Neg of Prop
```

There are several things that tripped you up:

- Set.fold operates on input that is a set, and does something for each element in the set. In your case, the input is a boolean clause, and the output is a set.
- You did not fully define what constitutes a literal. For a conjunction, the set of literals is the union of the literals on the left and on the right side. But what about a disjunction? The compiler error message means exactly that.

Here's what I think you are after:

```
let rec literals = function
    | P s -> Set.singleton s
    | Dis (x, y) -> Set.union (literals x) (literals y)
    | Con (x, y) -> Set.union (literals x) (literals y)
    | Neg x -> literals x
```

With that, you will get

```
> literals (Dis (P "A", Neg (Con (P "B", Con (P "A", P "C")))))
val it : Set<string> = set ["A"; "B"; "C"]
```

Comment: In [DNF](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjunctiveNormalForm.html), you cannot negate anything else than a [variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

Comment: @kaefer: That is true, but outside the scope of the question.